# Проблема с Model::findOrNew()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Выводится ошибка:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$vk

Участок кода:

```
$vk   = Socialite::driver('vkontakte')->user();
$user = User::findOrNew(['vk' => $vk->id]);

if ($user) {
    Auth::attempt(['vk' => $user->vk], 1);

    redirect()->route('home');
} else {
    $user->name  = $vk->name;
    $user->vk    = $vk->id;
    $user->email = $vk->email;
    $user->save();

    Auth::attempt(['vk' => $user->vk], 1);

    redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Я так полагаю, ошибка из-за того, что таблица целиком пустая, но как же быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибся в выборе метода.

Изменил на

```
User::firstOrNew(['vk' => $vk->id])
```